# How to implement brute force algorithm for string matching in php?

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm, pdo, brute-force

I have 2 tables and the schemes are like this:

**tb_keywords**

```
id_keyword
keyword
```

**tb_post**

```
id_post
description
```

I want to implement brute force algorithm for sting matching in php. If the description fit/similar with keyword so this description will insert into tb_post. I've tried to make this work, but it's not working.
There's no error message, just gave the blank result.

**HTML**

```
 <textarea type="text" class="form-control" name="description" id="description" placeholder="Description" required /></textarea>
```

**PHP**

```
$description = trim($_POST['description']);
$check = $db_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM  tb_keywords");
$check->execute();
$row=$check->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$positive = $row->keyword;

function brute_force($positive, $description)
{
    $n = strlen($description);
    $m = strlen($positive);
    for ($i = 0; i < $n-$m; $i++) {
        $j = 0;
        while ($j < $m && $description[$i+$j] == $positive[$j]) {
            $j++;
        }
        if ($j == $m) {
            return $i;
        }
        return -1;
    }
    $find[$i]=brute_force($positive, $description);
    $create=$db_con->prepare("INSERT INTO tb_post(description) VALUES(:description)");
    $create->bindParam(":description", $description);
    $create->execute();
    $row=$create->rowCount();
    if($row>0) {
        echo "success";
    } else {
        echo "fail";
    }

}
```

Comment: your code has some problems. it will never continue `for`-loop, and never reach to part of code after the `for`-loop. As I understand you have to try to find a keyword inside the description, but it will be easier to use [stripos()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.stripos.php) for case-insensitive search.

Answer (score 0):

To see if a particular word is in text, you can use a regular expression with word boundaries.

ie

> preg_match("/\bPHP\b/", "regex in PHP")   # match the word "PHP" in
>   string

```
$description = trim($_POST['description']);
$check = $db_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM  tb_keywords");
$check->execute();
while($row = $check->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {  
    $search = $row['keyword'];
    if (preg_match("/\b$search\b/", $description)) {  
        $create=$db_con->prepare("INSERT INTO tb_post(description) VALUES(:description)");
        $create->bindParam(":description", $description);
        $create->execute();
        $row=$create->rowCount();
        if($row>0) {
            echo "success";
        } else {
            echo "fail";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Regex used [**Thompson algorithm**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thompson's_construction)

Comment: Sorry, I have to use brute force algorithm. I can't change it because in my proposal I've written brute force as string matching algorithm that I use. Anyway thanks for answering my question.